# LINQ to Entities newbie question

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm not an experienced C# programmer and currently I'm doing some stuff with EF 3.5 and LINQ.

I have the following method and I'm quite sure it can be written in a better / shorter way.

Thanks for the help!

```
  public List<CustOrder> GetOrders(string supplierId, string locationId)
    {
        using (var ctx = new OrderEntities())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId))
            {
                var result = (from order in ctx.CustOrder
                              where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                                 && order.LocationId == locationId
                              select order).ToList();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = (from order in ctx.CustOrder
                              where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                                 && order.LocationId != ""
                              select order).ToList();
                return result;              
            }
        }
    }
```

My mistake: 
In 2nd linq query, the following line should be removed:

```
&& order.LocationId != ""
```

Comment: there is no EF 3.5, only 1.0, 4.0 and 4.1, so which one are you using?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I'm using EF with VS2008 & .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend this version as I find it more readable IMHO.

```
public List<CustOrder> GetOrders(string supplierId, string locationId)
{
    using (var ctx = new OrderEntities())
    {
        var query = from order in ctx.CustOrder
                    where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                    select order;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId))
        {
            query = query.Where(o => o.LocationId == locationId)
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer most since the code looks clean and easy to understand for others.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
 public List<CustOrder> GetOrders(string supplierId, string locationId)
 {
        using (var ctx = new OrderEntities())
        {
             var result = (from order in ctx.CustOrder
                          where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                          && string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId) ? true : order.LocationId == locationId
                                  select order).ToList();
             return result;
       }
 }
```

Comment: In the alternate case he wants != "".

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from order in ctx.CustOrder
                          where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                             && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId)
                               || order.LocationId == locationId)
                          select order).ToList();
            return result;
```

Comment: Please see my edited post; what I should do if I want to remove locationId from my linq query in case "locationId" is empty?

Comment: @Martyn Change "order.LocationId != String.Empty" to "true"

Comment: You can use boolean OR in that case. I've modified my code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Bala's does the null check and Talljoe's does the empty string check.  But this one does both:

```
 public List<CustOrder> GetOrders(string supplierId, string locationId)
 {
        using (var ctx = new OrderEntities())
        {
             var result = (from order in ctx.CustOrder
                                  where order.SupplierId == supplierId
                                     && ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(locationId) && order.LocationId == locationId) || 
                                         order.LocationId.Length > 0)
                                  select order).ToList();
             return result;
       }
 }
```

Also, checking string length is usually better than equality check against an empty string.